# Excel, conditional formatting column base on comparing two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel worksheet, with two sheets. First one (Worksheet 1) is big table (about 2000 rows), and in second (Worksheet2) I have only about 20 rows.

I need to check, if string in first column in each row in worksheet 1 is already in Worksheet 2, if so, make it green.

Thanks for solutions, both EXCEL or VBA will be appreciated :)

Comment: Try something like `isna(vlookup(string, table, ....))` as your conditional formatting condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In worksheet 1 you need to create a new column (say column AA) which uses the formula VLOOKUP to find the same data (if it exists) in the other sheet.  If is is not found VLOOKUP will return and error #N/A.  So you formula will look soemthing like:

IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheet2'!$SA$1:$X$9999, 3, false)),"NOT FOUND","FOUND")

You would then add conditional formatting to sheet1 column A that references the value in your new column (AA) and sets the colour accordingly.

If you don't know how to use VLOOKUP or get the conditional formatting to work, there are plenty of resource on the internet to help you learn these.  eg youtube channel ExcelisFun, WiseOwl.co.uk.

I hope this helps.

PS You do not need to use VBA to do this! In fact using a foumula can be preferable as if a single value changes it can cause the colours to be changed.

Harvey

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA, try as follow:

```
Public Sub findDuplicate()

    Dim sh1row, sh2Row As Long

    For sh1row = 1 To 20 'loop all row from Sheet2 (if more than 20, modify it)

        For sh2Row = 1 To 2000 'loop all row from Sheet1 (if more than 2000, modify it)

            'If A cell are equal
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & sh2Row) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & sh1row) Then

                'Change background color to green.
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & sh2Row).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

            End If

        Next sh2Row

    Next sh1row

End Sub
```

Comment: You will also need to change the colour if they are not equal

Comment: I think that questioner said only for equal case.